# Sync in-app purchases products with server

Tags: ios, swift, macos, in-app-purchase

I have a music app and I've implemented in-app purchases successfully and the user could buy the products. But I've plenty of products and it's very tough to manage it in apple and then on my site. Is there any option to automate this like when I upload a new product in my CMS it automatically adds it on apple IAP products and returns the product id?

Answer (score 1):

[spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/README.md#readme) from fastlane gem can be used to automate this. check this [post](https://andreygordeev.com/2017/09/14/create-iap-records-programmatically/).